# Select all values where condition is met and some additional

Tags: sql-server, select, conditional-statements

I have a table with fields:

```
| Accompanying measures (bool) | Category (String) | Instrument (String) |
```

Because the design of the application was not really meant to replace these, I altered the table `Instrument` with a field `ValidUntil` (Date Type) that has either a date where it was deprecated or `NULL` if it's still valid.
A view displays a mix of old data and new data. Old data may contain `Instruments` that have been deprecated, whereas new data won't.
If I display only the new Instruments `ValidUntil IS NULL` I break the page, because there are selected `Accompanying measures` that cannot be displayed, because they are not retrieved from the db.

**Tl;dr**
Edit: How can I select all `ValidUntil IS NULL` AND all entries where `ValidUntil != NULL, but HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure` is true.

```
SELECT
    a.AccompanyingMeasureID, a.InstrumentID, a.TaskID,         
    a.HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure, a.CategoryID
    , i.Name AS InstrumentName,     ic.Name AS CategoryName
FROM
    wc_AccompanyingMeasures AS a 
INNER JOIN
    wc_Instruments AS i ON a.InstrumentID = i.ID 
INNER JOIN
    wc_InstrumentCategories AS ic ON i.CategoryID = ic.ID
WHERE
    (a.TaskID = @TaskID) 
    // AND for TaskID all rows with HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure = 1
AND (i.ValidUntil IS NULL)
```

Comment: It's unclear what it is you're after here.  Can you clarify the bit after "TL:DR"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question, you have to use UNION ALL/UNION to combine the data sets of two different conditions.

```
--ValidUntil IS NULL
SELECT
    a.AccompanyingMeasureID, a.InstrumentID, a.TaskID,         
    a.HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure, a.CategoryID
    , i.Name AS InstrumentName,     ic.Name AS CategoryName
FROM wc_AccompanyingMeasures AS a 
INNER JOIN wc_Instruments AS i ON a.InstrumentID = i.ID 
INNER JOIN wc_InstrumentCategories AS ic ON i.CategoryID = ic.ID
WHERE (a.TaskID = @TaskID) 
AND (i.ValidUntil IS NULL) 
UNION ALL
--ValidUntil != NULL, but HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure is true
SELECT
    a.AccompanyingMeasureID, a.InstrumentID, a.TaskID,         
    a.HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure, a.CategoryID
    , i.Name AS InstrumentName,     ic.Name AS CategoryName
FROM wc_AccompanyingMeasures AS a 
INNER JOIN wc_Instruments AS i ON a.InstrumentID = i.ID 
INNER JOIN wc_InstrumentCategories AS ic ON i.CategoryID = ic.ID
WHERE (a.TaskID = @TaskID) 
AND (i.ValidUntil IS NOT NULL AND HasBeenSelectedAsAccompanyingMeasure='TRUE')
```